# how to config NAT-pmp on os x to support utun device?

Tags: ios, nat

I use SimepleTunnel project , iPhone app PacketTunel extion  work with  tunnel_server , but tunnel_server writev packet to kerel ,  how config pf to NAT traffic and the packets can route to Internet?

Mac OS X system Internetshare use /usr/libexec/natpmpd , this app only support ethernet device, can't support ip tunnel device

pf.conf

```
vpn_net = "192.168.3.0/24"  
ext_if = "en0"  
nat on en0  from $vpn_net to any ->  (en0)
```

check pf state

```
rMBP:etc root# pfctl -sa  
No ALTQ support in kernel  
ALTQ related functions disabled  
TRANSLATION RULES:  
nat on en0 inet from 192.168.3.0/24 to any -> (en0) round-robin
```

I use  tcpdump check write status

tcpdump -i utun0 and found 192.168.3.0/16 to my dnsserver  192.168.0.24, but no dnserver replay to 192.168.3.0/16

```
14:02:46.467038 IP 192.168.3.3.57257 > 192.168.0.245.domain: 38998+ A? guzzoni.apple.com. (35)  
14:02:46.467877 IP 192.168.3.3.49218 > 192.168.0.245.domain: 59621+ A? www.apple.com. (31)  
14:02:53.068894 IP 192.168.3.3.60834 > 192.168.0.245.domain: 52069+ A? apple.com. (27)  
14:02:53.069427 IP 192.168.3.3.57257 > 192.168.0.245.domain: 38998+ A? guzzoni.apple.com. (35)  
14:02:53.070072 IP 192.168.3.3.49218 > 192.168.0.245.domain: 59621+ A? www.apple.com. (31)  
14:03:05.456122 IP 192.168.3.3.60834 > 192.168.0.245.domain: 52069+ A? apple.com. (27)  
14:03:05.456653 IP 192.168.3.3.57257 > 192.168.0.245.domain: 38998+ A? guzzoni.apple.com. (35)  
14:03:05.457140 IP 192.168.3.3.49218 > 192.168.0.245.domain: 59621+ A? www.apple.com. (31)
```

how to configuring pf let utun packet  to NAT traffic ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
nat-anchor "simpleTunnel" 
load anchor "simpleTunnel" from "/etc/pf.anchors/simpleTunnel"
add upper lines to /etc/pf.conf
```

edit pf.anchors/simpleTunnel ,add

```
nat on en0 from 10.10.0.0/16 to any -> en0
```

then

```
sudo sysctl net.inet.ip.forwarding=1  
sudo sysctl net.inet.ip.fw.enable=1  
sudo pfctl -evf /etc/pf.conf
```

refer
   [develop forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/126646#126646)

Comment: sudo sysctl net.inet.ip.fw.enable=1 // ipfw replace by pf, you may need Turn on system firewall No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled